# Upload external library file (jQuery) to Ektron CMS

Tags: jquery, .net, file, content-management-system, ektron

I have a client who has commissioned me to create a new website. After pricing out a beautiful custom CMS lovingly hand-crafted in php, they then informed me that I must **shoehorn it into their existing CMS**.

The CMS appears to be built on a .NET system called Ektron. I am not a .NET developer, and I have no support from the provider.

The only manual I have been provided is one from pre-jQuery days — perhaps even pre-javascript days :-P  The title of the manual refers to "Ektron CMS200".

My wish is **to upload and link to the jQuery library** to give the site some contemporary functionality; however, I have been confounded at every turn.

Does anyone have any previous experience with this situation?

My thought right now is that I can somehow disguise the jQuery library as a css file (for which there is an upload option) and hack it to work as a jQuery library (as it should). However, this seems terribly round-about, and honestly a bit icky.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a "CMS200" then it's about 15 years old or so and not at all what anyone should be running today any more than someone should be running the first release of Wordpress. Or Windows 98.

If it's CMS200, then it's not .NET. If it's .NET, then it's at least CMS400.NET, at which point Ektron started moving toward numbered releases (6, 7.5, 8.02, etc.), the most recent of which is 9.1 SP3.

If you're looking for ways to upload a JS file, then you're being guided in entirely the wrong direction. If you're using HTML Content to create layouts, including headers, footers, and such, then you're being guided in entirely the wrong direction. None of this is a good practice for Ektron or any reasonable CMS.

Instead, you need access to (preferably) Visual Studio or a similar development environment. You'll need a local copy of the Ektron software so you can do real development against it.

Though I hate to be the bearer of bad news, I'm afraid you might be getting put into a situation that, at best, is ill-advised and, at worst, impossible.

If you really need to continue in this line, however, and really need to upload the file, my recommendation would be to upload it to the Library section of the Workarea. If you go to the Library and click on the root node, you should get an option to change the settings which control allowed file extensions. The Library will give you a file path that is clean and static so you can reference the file.

Of course, if all you need is JQuery, you can always use a CDN source, such as https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery/

Comment: Many of your points I knew or have had nagging in the back of my head; and I've been ruing the coming of the upload to the CMS platform. Still, I am of the breed who is determined to make it work. Stay tuned, and I will send an update next week. And thank you very much for the CDN source idea. I didn't even think of that! Signed, Bilbo.

Comment: I didn't mean to leave this question hanging, so here is my brief follow up. (Better late than never.) The Ektron solution was completely thrown out, and I rebuilt it on a different server. This was for all  of the reasons you state above, and more. I quoted parts of your excellent summary in my rationale to the client, and for that I thank you. And because it was just an excellent answer, I'm clicking accept. Apologies for the wait.

Comment: Glad you found a path forward and thanks for marking this as the answer (even if, after re-reading it, I feel like I sounded harsh...). Hope you've found something that allows you to follow proper SDLC as well as good content practices. Cheers!